# Handle JSON from stored procedure result API

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which post a API request an returns a JSON with info.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Ip_Api_Location]
    @IP varchar(max) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Objet AS Int
    DECLARE @Reponse as Varchar(8000)
    DECLARE @url VARCHAR(3000)
    DECLARE @Parametres VARCHAR(3000)
    DECLARE @Erreur int
    DECLARE @MessageErreur varchar(255)
    DECLARE @MessageErreurAvecNumero varchar(255)
    DECLARE @Statut int

    SET @url = 'http://ip-api.com/json/'+@IP
    --SET @Parametres = 
  
    exec @Erreur = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @Objet OUT;

    if @Erreur <> 0 
    begin 
        set @MessageErreur = 'sp_OACreate MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp.3.0 failed' 
        goto fin 
    end

    exec @Erreur = sp_OAMethod @Objet, 'open', NULL, 'POST', @url, false

    if @Erreur <> 0 
    begin 
        set @MessageErreur = 'sp_OAMethod Open failed' 
        goto fin 
    end

    exec @Erreur = sp_OAMethod @Objet, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

    if @Erreur <> 0 
    begin 
        set @MessageErreur = 'sp_OAMethod setRequestHeader failed' 
        goto fin 
    end

    exec @Erreur = sp_OAMethod @Objet, 'send', NULL, @Parametres

    if @Erreur <> 0 
    begin 
        set @MessageErreur = 'sp_OAMethod Send failed' 
        goto fin 
    end

    exec @Erreur = sp_OAGetProperty @Objet, 'status', @Statut OUT

    if @Erreur <> 0 
    begin 
        set @MessageErreur = 'sp_OAGetProperty read status failed' 
        goto fin 
    end

    exec @Erreur = sp_OAMethod @Objet, 'responseText', @Reponse OUTPUT

    if @Erreur <> 0 
    begin 
        set @MessageErreur = 'sp_OAMethod read response failed' 
        goto fin 
    end

   select Responce = @Reponse

   exec sp_OADestroy @Objet
   return

fin:
    print @MessageErreur
    exec sp_OADestroy @Objet

    set @MessageErreurAvecNumero = 'Erreur : ' + cast(@Erreur as varchar) + ' - ' + @MessageErreur
    Raiserror(@MessageErreurAvecNumero, 16, 1)

    return
END
```

And my simple SQL script that I don't know how to write it in order to get information from JSON result.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @json  varchar(MAX)
EXEC @json= Ip_Api_Location '60.8.216.98'Select @json   ---this  print the json
--{"status":"success","country":"China","countryCode":"CN"} 
Select @json --this print "0"
END
```

So I can't set the exec to a variable and handle the JSON. I tried to parse the JSON but I didn't succeeded.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wow! Haven't seen `goto` used like that since my early basic days... thought it was frowned upon :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is your `@json` variable is getting set to the return status that is indicating success for failure.

Easiest would be to use an OUTPUT parameter in your stored procedure.

Move the declaration of `@Reponse` variable in your stored procedure as a parameter and add OUTPUT, with json data use NVARCHAR(MAX):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Ip_Api_Location]
    @IP varchar(max)
    ,@Response nvarchar(MAX) OUTPUT
```

Then when you call with an OUTPUT parameter:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @json VARCHAR(MAX);

    EXEC [Ip_Api_Location] '60.8.216.98', @Response = @json OUTPUT;

    SELECT @json;
END;
```